What type of NAT does iptables MASQUERADE implement?
According to several sources (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719572/how-to-simulate-different-nat-behaviours), MASQUERADE in iptables behaves like a Symmetric NAT (i.e. Endpoint-Dependent Mapping and Endpoint-Dependent Filtering behavior).
I set up NAT on a Linux box in the following way:
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp7s0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate related,established -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.1.0/24 -o enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE

(enp7s0 is the LAN interface, 10.1.1.0/24 is the LAN subnet, enp1s0 is the WAN interface)
Then I run a NAT behavior test (on another system on the internal network) using STUN:
$ turnutils_natdiscovery stunserver2024.stunprotocol.org -m

-= Mapping Behavior Discovery =-

========================================
RFC 5780 response 1
No ALG: Mapped == XOR-Mapped
0: (1892021): INFO: IPv4. Response origin: : 3.132.228.249:3478
0: (1892021): INFO: IPv4. Other addr: : 3.135.212.85:3479
0: (1892021): INFO: IPv4. UDP reflexive addr: 1.2.3.4:58197
0: (1892021): INFO: IPv4. Local addr: : 0.0.0.0:58197

========================================
RFC 5780 response 2
No ALG: Mapped == XOR-Mapped
0: (1892021): INFO: IPv4. Response origin: : 3.135.212.85:3478
0: (1892021): INFO: IPv4. Other addr: : 3.132.228.249:3479
0: (1892021): INFO: IPv4. UDP reflexive addr: 1.2.3.4:58197
0: (1892021): INFO: IPv4. Local addr: : 0.0.0.0:58197

========================================
NAT with Endpoint Independent Mapping!
========================================

$ turnutils_natdiscovery stunserver2024.stunprotocol.org -f

-= Filtering Behavior Discovery =-

========================================
RFC 5780 response 1
No ALG: Mapped == XOR-Mapped
0: (1892024): INFO: IPv4. Response origin: : 3.132.228.249:3478
0: (1892024): INFO: IPv4. Other addr: : 3.135.212.85:3479
0: (1892024): INFO: IPv4. UDP reflexive addr: 1.2.3.4:34370
0: (1892024): INFO: IPv4. Local addr: : 0.0.0.0:34370
STUN receive timeout..
STUN receive timeout..

========================================
NAT with Address and Port Dependent Filtering!
========================================

As you can see, the mapping is Endpoint-Independent, therefore it would be a Port-Restricted Cone NAT according to the old terminology.
Just to be sure, I tested with OPNsense, and the test utility detected a Symmetric NAT correctly.
The question is: why are my findings different from the information I find online? Is there a way to have Symmetric NAT on Linux?

In the example of Symmetric NAT from the linked question:
echo "1" >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables --flush
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE --random
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT

For -j MASQUERADE, it is the --random that makes it symmetric NAT. Basically, STUN should see the firewall device using a different source port than the client.
There are some more examples and explanation in the answers here: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/67221/19702

Interesting. Thanks for the answer. --random does make the NAT symmetric. However, the port randomization behavior is orthogonal to the mapping and filtering behavior (see the definition of symmetric NAT here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3489.txt). I wonder if Linux allows to set up symmetric NAT that doesn't randomize ports or a port-restricted cone one that does.

The NAT behavior of netfilter can be classified as "non-deterministic" NAT in terms of RFC 4787, whether we specify "--random" or not.
netfilter internally manages connections by "address and port dependent" mapping and just avoid assigning the same port for connections from different local addresses to the same destination.
If we specify "--random", it first tries randam port, so it looks like Address and Port Dependent Mapping but it may assign the same port for connections from the same local address to different destinations (thus Endpoint Independent Mapping) if you are (un)lucky.
If we don't specify "--random", vice versa.
This draft provides the most detailed explanation of this among all official documents I know.
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-naito-nat-port-overlapping-01
As far as I know, netfilter doesn't have either symmetric NAT that doesn't randomize ports or a port-restricted cone one that does.
FYI, I added some different NAT behavior to my userspace NAT implementation https://github.com/ge9/rust-tun-nat.
